# Based on $GPRMC latitude and longitude draw a track line in windows forms using c#.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Based on $GPRMC latitude and longitude draw a track line in windows forms using c#.net ($GPRMC,083521.00,A,2849.29177,S,03204.19241,E,0.011,,091015,,,D*6E
$GPRMC,083521.50,A,2849.29176,S,03204.19241,E,0.020,,091015,,,D*68)

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What kind of experience do you have, how much does already work, etc...?